# how to make setup for google login in react native expo application with adb ? with new updates

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

When I add this line of code:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '',
  offlineAccess: true,
});",
```

It will give me this Error:

```
Error: RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully.
If you are using Expo, make sure you are using Custom dev client, not Expo go., js engine: hermes",i m also using expo-dev-client , after module's correct linking it will give me same error, i m using android adb,how to resolve this error , please provide me solution quickly. this is my package.json "{
  "name": "second_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "11": "^0.0.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.31",
    "expo": "~49.0.13",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-doctor": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-permissions": "^14.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "link": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-link": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "yet": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried all the things which is mention on the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) but still the error is same, I have tried `npx expo install react-native-google-signin/google-signin` for expo but doesn't do anything. Still there is error please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing use of [React-Native-Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io) (RNF), [Firebase Web Client SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master), and [React-Native Google Sign In](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin).

These are three very different libraries/API sets, and this is something you certainly do not want to do.

I wrote [this article](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/expo-react-native-firebase) that covers the differences between those RNF & Firebase Web Client libraries and recommended approaches.

If you are trying to use Firebase Authentication & its Google Sign In provider, then you do NOT want to use `react-native-google-sign-in`.  If you are not using Firebase, then you should NOT be using RNF or Firebase Web Client.

Make a choice as to an approach, pick a library, and remove the others.  Then use the ***one*** API that you decide to stay with properly by following the API documentation for that ***one*** API.

Comment: sir i want to know how to use google login in reactnative expo android application. it doesn't matter weather it is with google cloud or react-native-firebase , i m unable to resolve the library of  React-Native Google Sign In, in my project please provide me solution.

Comment: This all depends on what you mean by "google login".  There are several meanings to it.  If you are not using Firebase, then remove both `firebase` and `react-native-firebase`.  If you are using Firebase, then are you looking to leverage the "Google Auth Provider" for Firebase Authentication?  This all comes down to understanding YOUR BUSINESS REQUIREMENTS....the technical requirements (i.e. which APIs to use) comes after you understand those business requirements.

Comment: bro i have tried with fresh expo project for using google api and rnf so it still do anything, bro if possible will you please tell me steps

Comment: It is not possible to tell you the steps when we don't know what it is. You're actually trying to accomplish. "Google sign in" can mean a number of things, based on what your back end is. Google API and RNF and trying to accomplish the task tells me that you aren't sure what the task actually is.